# Firefox+noscript v.s. systemd-nspawn - ABE denial

Tags: security, firefox, systemd-nspawn

```
    [ABE] < LOCAL> Deny on {GET http://jessie/icons/openlogo-75.png <<< http://jessie/ - 1}
    SYSTEM rule:
    Site LOCAL
    Accept from LOCAL
    Deny
```

i.e. pages on http://jessie cannot load images or any other sub-resource.

```
$ getent ahosts jessie
192.168.122.74 STREAM jessie
192.168.122.74 DGRAM
192.168.122.74 RAW
fe80::b4f5:2ff:feb9:b12f STREAM
fe80::b4f5:2ff:feb9:b12f DGRAM
fe80::b4f5:2ff:feb9:b12f RAW
```

NoScript version 5.0.5

"jessie" is a systemd-nspawn container.  Its name is resolved by `nss-mymachines`.  Why does this happen, what is the diagreement between systemd and NoScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[barbaz on the forums](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=22925#p88420) suggests this can happen if "jessie" resolves to both LOCAL and non-LOCAL address.  It sounds like NoScript interprets it as an attack like the "DNS rebinding attack".

IPv6 link-local addresses (your `fe80...` addresses) are not treated as LOCAL.  I think the explanation is it would break some sites on the Web which have mis-configured DNS :(.  https://github.com/avian2/noscript/blob/ebc093642cb9645bc18b63fc151d3b00063b97ee/xpi/chrome/content/noscript/DNS.js#L337

I think it's possible to disable IPv6 inside the container, using the sysctl `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`.  But I'm not sure this is a great response, for what is an limitation in NoScript's IPv6 support.

I can work around it in NoScript by adding this at the very top of NoScript Options > Advanced > ABE > SYSTEM:

```
# NoScript default rule chokes when name resolves to both IPv6 LLA
# and IPv4 "private" address.
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370485/firefoxnoscript-v-s-systemd-nspawn-abe-denials/370486#370486
# Treat nodots domain as (an independent) LAN.
# Useful for nss-mymachines.   I think LLMNR would also be affected.
Site ^https?://[^.]*[:/]
Accept from ^https?://[^.]*[:/]
Deny
```